# Cannot read property 'units' of undefined in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Am new into Angular and am trying to load a dropdown with static values (values defined in a .ts file).
While am trying to load the array with the values, am getting error message as:

Cannot read property 'correlationDepthUnits' of undefined.

Am providing the whole code below:

What I have tried:

**Constant.ts**

```
export class Constant {
public static Units = [
        {unit_name : "ft", unit_value : "ft", unit_description : "Feet"},
        {unit_name : "m", unit_value : "m", unit_description : "Meters"},
        {unit_name : "km", unit_value : "km", unit_description : "Kilometers"},
        {unit_name : "yd", unit_value : "yd", unit_description : "Yards"},
        {unit_name : "mi", unit_value : "mi", unit_description : "Miles"},
    ]
}
```

**units.ts**

```
export class units{
    unit_name : string;
    unit_value : string;
    unit_description : string;
}
```

**main-page.Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { units } from '../../models/units';
import { Constant } from '../../Constant';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-well-data',
  templateUrl: './well-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./well-data.component.css']
})
export class WellDataComponent implements OnInit {
  Units : units[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUnits();
  }

  getUnits() {
    debugger;
    /*
    for (var index = 0; index < Constant.Units.length; index++)
    {
      this.Units[index].unit_name = Constant.Units[index].unit_name;
      this.Units[index].unit_value = Constant.Units[index].unit_value;
      this.Units[index].unit_description = Constant.Units[index].unit_description;
    }
    */

    Constant.Units.forEach(function(item){
      this.Units.push(item);
    });
  }

}
```

**Template file**

```
<select class="form-control input-types fonts" id="corrDepth">
     <option *ngFor="let unit of correlationDepthUnits" 
              [value]="unit.unit_value">{{unit.unit_name}}
     </option>>
</select>
```

Please help me through this.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste template file too, where you are displaying the dropdown with the static values?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti - I have added the template file.

Comment: Ok, aside from the arrow function part in mpstvs' answer (which is correct), you use `correlationDepthUnits` in the template, but the property in the component is called `Units`.

Comment: Well, where did you declare `correlationDepthUnits` in the ts file? I think it should be `Units`

Comment: yeah sorry its Units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use arrow function instead anonymous function:

```js
Constant.Units.forEach((item) => {
  this.Units.push(item);
});
```

This is because an arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used. Arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not present in the current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this from its enclosing scope.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thanks. I will check with this and let you know.

Comment: Hi, it worked. Thanks.
Understood the explanation for arrow function.

I even tried like the below code:

`for (var index = 0; index < Constant.CorrelationDepthUnits.length; index++)
    {
      this.Units[index].unit_name = Constant.Units[index].unit_name;
      this.Units[index].unit_value = Constant.Units[index].unit_value;
      this.Units[index].unit_description = Constant.Units[index].unit_description;
    }`

Even this was also not working. But, here "this" should not be ambiguous right. Then why this code was not working and was throwing the same error.

Comment: I think this is because `units` is an empty array and reversal at `index` returns `undefined`. This can be fixed by adding element initialization at first line in loop: `this.Units[index] = new units()`